# how to pass props through <Link>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to pass props through 'Link' tag so I implemented it that way:

```
 <ul className="list-group mb-4">
{posts.map(post=>(<li key={post.name} className="list-group-item">{post.name}<Row style={{paddingLeft:800}}><Col><Link to={{
                            pathname: '/starship', aboutProps: {
                              name:post.name,
                            model:post.model,
                            manufacturer:post.manufacturer
                            }
                          }} ><Button  >  show more</Button></Link></Col></Row></li>))}
</ul>
```

then I am trying to access the props through   props.location.aboutProps

```
<div>
        <h1>{props.location.aboutProps.name}</h1>
    </div>)}
```

but I am getting this error:

[image]

and here I tried to console.log(props) and it's giving me an empty object(I don't know why it's empty), it's the object in "starship.js:3"  :

[image]

here's codesandbox but the project is heavy there so it currently doesn't render but you can see the whole code in it:https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-dijkstra-hw0qh?file=/src/Components/HomePage.js:95-120 and you can play around with it on your device even if it the components don't render

Comment: what about `props.aboutProps.name`?

Comment: better `console.log(props)`. Then check path was correct

Comment: @Simone undefined too

Comment: @prasanth in which file/component?

Comment: `console.log` where did you used this code `{props.location.aboutProps.name}`  component

Comment: I did it now and it showed nothing because already in that directory there's the error in the screenshot above so it doesn't work to console.log() it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do it

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/toSomeThing',
  state: {
    any: "any"
  }
}}>Hi</Link>
```

Anytime you pass data along via the state property, that data will be available in the component as a property on props.location.state.

```
const { any } = this.props.location.state
```

Comment: what's different from my solution?

Comment: Because there are only two ways to pass data from a Link through to the new route: URL parameters and state. URL parameters work great for strings but aren’t meant for any other data types. By making the Links to prop an object, you can pass along any sort of data you need under the state property and that data can be accessed in the new route under props.location.state.

Comment: ok, but the props is already empty and the problem is not probably in passing it through router but it needs to be defined correctly from the first component, that's what I think..

Comment: because I already used the syntax in your answer and the error disappeared but it gave empty page

Comment: I tried this in my code, it works as expected, just log post in map function to make sure there is data

Comment: post is not empty

Comment: please try to copy/paste the code in the sandbox in your project and tell me what happens

Comment: actually post/posts is not also empty, so what could be the difference to my project?

Comment: I don't see your code to figure out what is different
please try to make an example in sandbox also

Comment: acutely you may need to wrap your starship component with HOC withRouter from react-router-dom to access props.location

Comment: yes, I think the problem in the structure or something because the javascript is all correct, tell me what's withRouter?

Comment: Yes, I am tired of your project structure, it's work for me in sandbox example, but after refresh the page it's back to raise an error again maybe this related to Sandbox engine       withRouter Docs: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter

Answer (score 0):

```
<Link to={{ 
  pathname: '/starship', 
  state:{
     name:post.name,
     model:post.model,
     manufacturer:post.manufacturer
  }}}>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

It's not working cause you can not pass any key inside to object
As per [react router documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object) you have to pass external data with state key only.
So It'll be like

```
<Link to={{
    pathname='/startship'
    state={
       aboutProps: {
          name:post.name,
          model:post.model,
          manufacturer:post.manufacturer
          }
    }
 }}
</Link>
```

Comment: it's giving me same error, I will attach a codesandbox in minutes